# Limit Bing Autosuggest to rules contained in Custom Search instance configuration ID

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing, autosuggest

Using the Microsoft Cognitive services: Bing Custom Search API and Bing Autosuggest API, you create an account at customsearch.ai and configure an instance with allowed and blocked domains. The configuration ID of this instance is used with the Custom Search to limit results based on the domains within this instance.

This configuration ID however does not limit Autosuggest results to those same domains - it's possible to type "Frankie" and see a suggestion of "Frankie & Benny's" when used for example, with restrictions of three.co.uk. Naturally there are no actual results on the site for this, as they have been restricted by the configuration ID to information available on three.co.uk.

Given that Google's paid search is being discontinued but offered this functionality, I'd really like to see this with the Bing version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bing's Web Search API then pull the page titles from the resulting web pages for your autocomplete suggestions. This ensures that your suggestions will always be actual page titles from your site.

Answer (score 0):

Bing Custom Search API now provides autosuggest capability for your domains. This was added as a feature recently - 7th May. You can give it a try.